# Is there documentation for configuring and using terminal?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I just want to use my computer from the terminal. I have read through the Apple Terminal Help documentation, but am looking for more instruction.

Comment: I assume from your question you are using Mac OS. Please verify this.
*Terminal* is a very broad term. 
Also - what are you hoping to achieve through your terminal? This question is too broad

Comment: Yes, thank you for helping clarify. I am using Mac OS and want to use terminal to navigate my files and folders. I also want to browse web pages from the terminal.

Comment: Not just too broad but innately off-topic. We explicitly disallow questions asking for the location of an off-site resources, and *additionally* require that questions be specific to software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this [2003 pdf doc](https://www.apple.com/server/docs/Command_Line.pdf). it is pretty comprehensive and still relevant to this day. i suggest setting up a [developer account](https://developer.apple.com/) if you are keen to learn more.

As for the things you intend to do on terminal,

- `man` is your great dictionary assistant
- `cd`, `ls` and `pwd` are your great buddies in navigating around the files and folders
- `curl` is your great bestie for browsing web pages
- `.bash_profile` is where your configuration lies

Hope this helps!